# Unwanted button text outline only in MotoG5

Tags: android, android-layout

I have simple button

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="#d22d2d"
    android:text="Proceed"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    />
```

- On MotoG5 it shows unwanted outline on `Button` text, while **it is okay in other devices**.
- This text outline does not appear in `TextView`. I tested it.

[image: My screenshot]

I checked another app in mobile, all apps (Gmail, Contacts etc.) having same behaviour.

[image: other app]

I think there should be some theme fix to remove this unwanted outline in MotoG5.

Comment: Where the border is ???

Comment: If All app have same behavior, then you need to change some settings.

Comment: Yah same here, I post total 3 comments but now showing only 1

Comment: Is this some kind of bug, or this can be new feature of SO? Some higher reputation users have right to remove comments. but why someone will remove our comments?

Comment: @ChiragSavsani yes it is a setting, see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it from **Settings > Accessibility > Set off to High-contrast text**

Your problem will solve.

Comment: Any other solution? Without disabling High-contrast text